# How to create ANSI C file in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c, visual-studio

Like in the title - how can I create a single ANSI C source file in Visual Studio 2012? I don't see any appropriate choice for ansi c files in file->new file option.

And one more thing - is there any shortcut for compiling and running?

Comment: Shortcuts: Build & Debug: `F5`, Build & Run: `Ctrl + F5`

Comment: Remember, extension of file doesn't matter. Particularly, in operating systems other than Windows. The only two things making C file is
1) using of C language
2) and compiling of this file with appropriate compiler and compiler command line switches

For example, I can create on my Linux station file 1.cpp with C source code and compile it with gcc compiler or g++ compiler. Both are part of GNU C package, but first compiler will treat source file as C and second as C++.

Comment: Please take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55.aspx It is command line switches for microsoft c/c++ compiler.

Comment: @George Gaál: the default rules in many tools, including GNU make would disagree. While the OSs don't care (by the way, Windows doesn't care either), the tools often do care. Fun fact: do your little experiment with the `.cpp` file and a proper `GNUmakefile` (or `Makefile`) and see it fail ;)

Answer (score 5):

There is no direct way for doing what you want (even in older Visual Studio versions). And C++ source files often serve the same purpose, but of course there are legit reasons for using plain C files instead. Don't worry, I'm not even going to argue that, because I still have to maintain several code bases that are C for a good reason (though not everywhere the same reason).

If you really need to do this more than once and can't use some tool that builds your project from existing source files, for example, you can do it like so:

1. open a file manager as admin (privileged user)
2. In the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcprojectitems` take a copy of the existing `newc++file.cpp` and name the copy `newcfile.c` (you can also customize this "skeleton file").
3. Now locate the file `NewItems.vsdir` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\VCNewItems` and add the line I am listing below.
4. start/restart Visual Studio and you should see it under the Visual C++ category

Done.

```
..\VCProjectItems\NewCFile.c|{1B027A40-8F43-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}|C files (.c)|10|Creates a file containing C source code|{1B027A40-8F43-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}|9031|4096|#1077
```

Notes:

- you will still see the icon with the `++`, but that's cosmetics. It must be one of the resource identifiers `#<number>` that defines this.
- the GUID is pointing to a binary containing the resources. If you don't need them, it is legit to leave the field empty (needs to be one blank space, though) to my knowledge. The GUID, you fill find (registry search) points to `.\VC\vcpackages\vcpkg.dll` ... so you can probably browse the resources there and find something more fitting if you feel like it.
- turns out the 9031 is a resource ID, too. Probably the `#<number>` items refer to string resources in particular. You could choose 9033 as your icon instead (more neutral). [IconsExt](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/iconsext.html) can help to find a suitable resource.
- obviously you *may* need to adjust the path names, depending on your locale.

Comment: Or seriously, just create an empty file, and give it a .c extension.  What you've given here is a very long-winded approach. (But it does give an elegant option)

Comment: @Arafangion: ... long-winded perhaps, but first and foremost it is an answer to the question that all others had been dodging so far. Besides, it's good to know your tools and VS hides way too many things. By the way, creating your own project wizard involves rather similar steps and I would say that is very useful indeed.

Comment: Indeed, it's well answered. +1.

Comment: (old answer, I know). I got a nice C icon by putting a 0 in the field (VS2013), like this: `NewCFile.c|0|C File (.c)|10|Creates a file containing C source code|{1B027A40-8F43-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}|0|0|cfile.c`. MS has a document on how this all works: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166192.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could build one project before creating a C source file, this seems to be a convention for MSVS series. Wish to be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Create a C++ file, then give it a .c extension.  On windows in at least some versions of the MSVC compiler, that will cause it to be compiled with C.

That's with some version of ANSI C - you won't get any of the niceties of modern C implementations from the past decade or so.

Frankly, I'd use whatever subset of C++ and C99 that you get away with, and use the C++ compiler.

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/829488/en-us) MS Support link contains useful infos for your question; unfortunately, I'm not sure this is applicable to new VS 2012.

Let me know if this solves! Bye!